# Spark Dataframe .does saving the output of an ordered dataframe to a parquet file preserve order

Tags: apache-spark-sql

if I  create a dataframe from a call to the orderBy method in the Dataframe class.

I then save the result of this dataframe to a  parquet  file.

Does this write  operation preserve the order of the rows?

I cannot find any documentation that could be present any guarantees .